# Error when Tapping multiple times on EditText

Tags: android

in the MainActivity, i have two textviews (username and password)
i discovered a wierd error that crashes my app after i keep on tapping on the textfields form some time.

please any help would be appreciated.

the Error:

```
01-22 11:51:53.523  29093-29093/com.myapplication
E/InputEventReceiver﹕ Exception dispatching input event.
01-22 11:51:53.523  29093-29093/ com.myapplication 
E/MessageQueue-JNI﹕ Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
01-22 11:51:53.543  29093-29093/ com.myapplication 
E/MessageQueue-JNI﹕ android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class <unknown>
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:626)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:675)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:700)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:470)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
            at android.widget.Editor$ActionPopupWindow.initContentView(Editor.java:3513)
            at android.widget.Editor$PinnedPopupWindow.<init>(Editor.java:2693)
            at android.widget.Editor$ActionPopupWindow.<init>(Editor.java:3437)
            at android.widget.Editor$ActionPopupWindow.<init>(Editor.java:3437)
            at android.widget.Editor$HandleView.showActionPopupWindow(Editor.java:4505)
            at android.widget.Editor$InsertionHandleView.showWithActionPopup(Editor.java:4935)
            at android.widget.Editor$InsertionHandleView.onTouchEvent(Editor.java:4987)
            at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:8160)
            at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:8368)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4788)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4649)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4207)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4261)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4230)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4341)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4238)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4398)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4207)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4261)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4230)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4238)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4207)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6584)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:6501)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6472)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6437)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6664)
            at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
            at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
            at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:138)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:131)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5653)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:675)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:700)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:470)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
            at android.widget.Editor$ActionPopupWindow.initContentView(Editor.java:3513)
            at android.widget.Editor$PinnedPopupWindow.<init>(Editor.java:2693)
            at android.widget.Editor$ActionPopupWindow.<init>(Editor.java:3437)
            at android.widget.Editor$ActionPopupWindow.<init>(Editor.java:3437)
            at android.widget.Editor$HandleView.showActionPopupWindow(Editor.java:4505)
            at android.widget.Editor$InsertionHandleView.showWithActionPopup(Editor.java:4935)
            at android.widget.Editor$InsertionHandleView.onTouchEvent(Editor.java:4987)
            at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:8160)
            at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:8368)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4788)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4649)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4207)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4261)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4230)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4341)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4238)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4398)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4207)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4261)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4230)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4238)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4207)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6584)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:6501)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6472)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6437)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6664)
            at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
            at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
            at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:138)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:131)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5653)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=15; index=665
            at android.content.res.StringBlock.get(StringBlock.java:65)
            at android.content.res.XmlBlock$Parser.getPooledString(XmlBlock.java:459)
            at android.content.res.TypedArray.loadStringValueAt(TypedArray.java:721)
            at android.content.res.TypedArray.getString(TypedArray.java:125)
            at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:1522)
            at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:921)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:675)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:700)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:470)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
            at android.widget.Editor$ActionPopupWindow.initContentView(Editor.java:3513)
            at android.widget.Editor$PinnedPopupWindow.<init>(Editor.java:2693)
            at android.widget.Editor$ActionPopupWindow.<init>(Editor.java:3437)
            at android.widget.Editor$ActionPopupWindow.<init>(Editor.java:3437)
            at android.widget.Editor$HandleView.showActionPopupWindow(Editor.java:4505)
            at android.widget.Editor$InsertionHandleView.showWithActionPopup(Editor.java:4935)
            at android.widget.Editor$InsertionHandleView.onTouchEvent(Editor.java:4987)
            at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:8160)
            at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:8368)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4788)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4649)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4207)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4261)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4230)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4341)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4238)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4398)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4207)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4261)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4230)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4238)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4207)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6584)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:6501)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6472)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6437)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6664)
            at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
            at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
            at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:138)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:131)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5653)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-22 11:51:53.543  29093-29093/ com.myapplication 
D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
01-22 11:51:53.543  29093-29093/ com.myapplication 
W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x417f2da0)
01-22 11:51:53.543  29093-29093/ com.myapplication 
E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.myapplication, PID: 29093
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class <unknown>
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:626)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:675)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:700)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:470)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
            at android.widget.Editor$ActionPopupWindow.initContentView(Editor.java:3513)
            at android.widget.Editor$PinnedPopupWindow.<init>(Editor.java:2693)
            at android.widget.Editor$ActionPopupWindow.<init>(Editor.java:3437)
            at android.widget.Editor$ActionPopupWindow.<init>(Editor.java:3437)
            at android.widget.Editor$HandleView.showActionPopupWindow(Editor.java:4505)
            at android.widget.Editor$InsertionHandleView.showWithActionPopup(Editor.java:4935)
            at android.widget.Editor$InsertionHandleView.onTouchEvent(Editor.java:4987)
            at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:8160)
            at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:8368)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4788)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4649)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4207)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4261)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4230)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4341)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4238)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4398)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4207)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4261)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4230)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4238)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4207)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6584)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:6501)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6472)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6437)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6664)
            at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
            at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
            at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:138)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:131)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5653)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:675)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:700)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:470)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
            at android.widget.Editor$ActionPopupWindow.initContentView(Editor.java:3513)
            at android.widget.Editor$PinnedPopupWindow.<init>(Editor.java:2693)
            at android.widget.Editor$ActionPopupWindow.<init>(Editor.java:3437)
            at android.widget.Editor$ActionPopupWindow.<init>(Editor.java:3437)
            at android.widget.Editor$HandleView.showActionPopupWindow(Editor.java:4505)
            at android.widget.Editor$InsertionHandleView.showWithActionPopup(Editor.java:4935)
            at android.widget.Editor$InsertionHandleView.onTouchEvent(Editor.java:4987)
            at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:8160)
            at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:8368)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4788)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4649)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4207)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4261)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4230)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4341)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4238)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4398)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4207)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4261)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4230)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4238)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4207)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6584)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:6501)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6472)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6437)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6664)
            at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
            at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
            at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:138)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:131)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5653)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=15; index=665
            at android.content.res.StringBlock.get(StringBlock.java:65)
            at android.content.res.XmlBlock$Parser.getPooledString(XmlBlock.java:459)
            at android.content.res.TypedArray.loadStringValueAt(TypedArray.java:721)
            at android.content.res.TypedArray.getString(TypedArray.java:125)
            at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:1522)
            at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:921)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:675)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:700)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:470)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
            at android.widget.Editor$ActionPopupWindow.initContentView(Editor.java:3513)
            at android.widget.Editor$PinnedPopupWindow.<init>(Editor.java:2693)
            at android.widget.Editor$ActionPopupWindow.<init>(Editor.java:3437)
            at android.widget.Editor$ActionPopupWindow.<init>(Editor.java:3437)
            at android.widget.Editor$HandleView.showActionPopupWindow(Editor.java:4505)
            at android.widget.Editor$InsertionHandleView.showWithActionPopup(Editor.java:4935)
            at android.widget.Editor$InsertionHandleView.onTouchEvent(Editor.java:4987)
            at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:8160)
            at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:8368)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4788)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4649)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4207)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4261)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4230)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4341)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4238)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4398)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4207)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4261)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4230)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4238)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4207)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6584)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:6501)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6472)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6437)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6664)
            at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
            at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
            at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:138)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:131)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5653)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

MainActivity

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       if(getResources().getConfiguration().locale.toString().equals("en_US") || getResources().getConfiguration().locale.toString().equals("en"))
        {
            lang="en";
        }
        else
        {
            lang="ar";
        }

try {
            // Instantiate the gesture detector with the application context and an implementation of GestureDetector.OnGestureListener
            mDetector = new GestureDetectorCompat(this,this);
            // Initialize gesture detector - double tap listener
            mDetector.setOnDoubleTapListener(this);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error in In MainActivity Gesture Error: "+e.toString());

        }
username = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);

ry {
            password.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                    if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO) {
                        login(findViewById(android.R.id.content));
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e(TAG,"Error in password.setOnEditorActionListener: "+e);
        }



public void login(View view) {

        String loginUserName = username.getText().toString();
        String loginPassword = password.getText().toString();
}
```

**NOTE:I JUST NOTICED THAT IT CRASHES WHEN A TEXT IS WRITTEN IN THE EDIT TEXT AND THE BLUE CURSOR IS TAPPED. ALSO ON HTC ONE M8(4.4.4) NO ERROR OCCURS BUT ON SAMSUNG GRAND DOUS 2(4.4.2) THE ERROR OCCURS**

Comment: Please show related Code

Comment: Why the down vote, i will provide information if asked plus i don't know what this error means and i searched for it but none fits my case

Comment: would you like me to post the xml layout? because i really don't know what part of the code is related to this error

Comment: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class <unknown>. And from PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56). So post that part

Comment: are you using some array when you tab on textview ??

Comment: i will post the oncreate method in a minute

Comment: "debug this code" is not a question.

Comment: Ther's also a ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException I guess we are missing something else

Comment: i just realized that in another activity, the edittext gave the same error when pressing on the blue cursor, but on the htc it didnt so i guess this is a bug and is solved in 4.4.4?

Comment: i will try to find out how to handle the tap on the cursor

Comment: post the code where you handle the double taps

Comment: still i did not search for that because im trying to figure out why is this happening!. i even commented out everything in oncreate method and just left the edit texts and it crashed.

Comment: wait a minute, are we talking about TextView views or EditText views?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I FOUND OUT THE PROBLEM!! but if someone can explain to me why was this causing such a problem.

in the style.xml i removed

sans-serif-monospace

and it worked !

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone else encounters the following two symptoms:

> MessageQueue-JNI﹕ android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class
>
> Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=15; index=665

The solution seems to be removing items such as:

```
<item name="android:fontFamily"></item>
```

From your styles.xml file. Doing so solved the issue for me.

Comment: Yes, there appears to be a bug somewhere in here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/kitkat-release/core/java/android/widget/TextView.java `android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:984)` which does not agree with fontFamily. I am trying to find a workaround to set fonts.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, setting fontFamily on a Button or TextView in a field that does not have the correct parent, i.e. android:Widget.TextView or android:Widget.Holo.Button, causes this crash with the stack trace listed below.

The fix from [here](https://github.com/rengwuxian/MaterialEditText/issues/162) worked for me:

```
<style name="TextViewStyle" parent="android:Widget.TextView">
        <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-medium</item>
</style>

<style name="ButtonStyle" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Button">
        <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-medium</item>
</style>
```

and then applying the style with:

```
<item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/TextViewStyle</item>
<item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/ButtonStyle</item>
```

avoids this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=33; index=1703
        at android.content.res.StringBlock.get(StringBlock.java:65)
        at android.content.res.XmlBlock$Parser.getPooledString(XmlBlock.java:458)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.loadStringValueAt(TypedArray.java:721)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getString(TypedArray.java:125)
        at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:984)
        at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:107)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.<init>(AppCompatButton.java:63)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.<init>(AppCompatButton.java:59)
        at android.support.v7.internal.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:101)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:802)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:832)
        at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:684)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:839)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:745)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106)
        at com.spiceworks.ui.activities.TicketDetailActivity.onCreate(TicketDetailActivity.java:43)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```